# Error in custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am getting the below error while using angular.js filter methos.

> Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
    at adminCustomerViewController.js:1387
    at fn (eval at compile (angularjs.js:212), <anonymous>:4:464)
    at dirPagination.js:100
    at Object.<anonymous> (angularjs.js:115)
    at n.$digest (angularjs.js:130)
    at n.$apply (angularjs.js:133)
    at g (angularjs.js:87)
    at K (angularjs.js:91)
    at XMLHttpRequest.z.onload (angularjs.js:92)
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
<input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="letter">
    <tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | startsWithLetter:letter | orderBy:'rest_name')) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
     <td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td>
     <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
```

My controller side code is given below.

```
customerView.filter('startsWithLetter', function () {
    return function (items, letter) {
        //console.log('items',items);
        var filtered = [];
        var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            if (letterMatch.test(item.rest_name.substring(0, 1))) {
                filtered.push(item);
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    };
});
customerView.controller('adminCustomerViewController',function($scope,$state,$http,$window,$timeout,Upload,focusInputField){
    $http({
        method:'GET',
        url:"php/customerInfo.php?action=disp",
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    }).then(function successCallback(response){
        console.log('res',response.data);
        $scope.listOfCustomerData=response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response) {
    })
})
```

Actually i am implementing the search functionality here . Here my requirement is when user will type at least first letter of the restaurant name(`i.e-rest_name`) the related restaurant will filter from the table. Suppose i have many restaurant like `Anjum,A&P Chinese Food Express,Bookers BBQ & Crab Shack,Butcher And The Baker,    Cactus Club Stephen Avenue,Cactus Club - Macleod Trail`. Here when user is typing only `a` inside the search box the names started with a should filter  . I did something but got the above error.Please help me.

Comment: Probably, your `listOfCustomerData` is undefined.

Comment: No,all data are displaying in table.Its not undefined.

Comment: can you please include `listOfCustomerData` array?

Comment: put this on top "function (items, letter)" & return directly

Comment: Let me to add another thing here.what i am getting from console.Initialy its throwing this error once alldata is fetching to `listOfCustomerData` object its not coming at all.

Comment: I think items is undefined.

Comment: Can you put this -> `if (!letter) { return items; }` in the first line of your filter please?

Comment: yes,i did that and it came properly.But here another problem is only typing by one letter from the total name its filtering when user is typing next letter ,no filter functionality is working.The table is showing blank. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want only those *objects* that have the corresponding letters to input
you don't need to use `Regexp`.

Here a snippet working:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])

  .controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [  
       {  
          "name":"USA"
       },
       {  
          "name":"Japan"
       },
       {  
          "name":"France"
       },
       {  
          "name":"Canada"
       },
       {  
          "name":"China"
       }
    ];
  })

  .filter('startsWith', function() {
    return function(items, search) {
      if (!search) {
        return items;
      }
      search = search.toLowerCase();
      return items.filter(function(element) {
        return element.name.toLowerCase().substring(0, search.length).indexOf(search) != -1;
      });
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  <label for="letter">Filter: </label>
  <input type="text" id="letter" ng-model="letter">
  <hr>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="country in countries | startsWith: letter">
        <td ng-bind="country.name"></td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can test it. Its only working while putting the first letter of the country name. while putting the total name the list is showing blank.Both condition should work.Suppose i typed `c` its filtering properly but when i am typing `ch` the list is blank.So both condition should work.

Comment: Please check when i typed `c` first `France` is also coming in the list. I need suppose user typed `c` inside the text box only country name starting with c `i.e-Canada,China` should come and when user will again type `ca` then the list should show `Canada` or for `ch` it should display `China`. Actually i need this type search with each letter.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type Restaurant Name" name="q" type="text" ng-model="letter">
    <tr dir-paginate="cus in ($parent.labelResults=(listOfCustomerData  | filter : letter )) | itemsPerPage:5 track by $index" current-page="currentPage">
     <td>{{itemsPerPage *(currentPage-1)+$index+1}}</td>
     <td>{{cus.rest_name}}</td>
    </tr>   
    </tbody>
```

its best to use `filter` given in angular as comapred to make your custom filter

Comment: No,its not filtering as per expected.

Comment: have your data is coming perfect ?

Comment: Yes.initially i have all data inside the table.Please read mu comment above.